How can we clone specific folders in a repo using Azure DevOps
we are fairly new to Azure DevOps.  we are wondering what our best options for our scenario would be,
we want to make project of all of our SQL Reporting services reports that are created.  many ppl manage and create reports specific to certain areas.  we want to manage these in the repos via different folders etc.
how is it possible to clone specific folders only and not the entire repo?
created specific folders
but clone of repo doesn't specify which files/folders to clone
do we need to create pipelines that can call specific folders?

All in all, this does not seem like good practice, but I do not have a perfect solution, either. Depending on how experienced the team is with Git, you might want to consider submodules or separate repos altogether?

Have tried the steps mentioned in the answer below that using the commands "git clone -n --depth=1 --filter=tree:0 <repo-clone-URL>", "git sparse-checkout set --no-cone <folder-name-01> <folder-name-02> ..." and "git checkout"? Does it work for you? @braddo

You can reference the steps below to clone/check out only the specified folders from the Git repository.
For example, I have a Git repository on Azure DevOps, and need to only check out the 'script' and 'src' folders.

The steps to check out the 'script' and 'src' folders:

Run the 'git clone' command like as below. It will set the local repository but with an empty folder which is named as the repository name.
git clone -n --depth=1 --filter=tree:0 https://<organization-name>@dev.azure.com/<organization-name>/<project-name>/_git/<repository-name>



Go to the folder of the local repository and run the 'git sparse-checkout' command like as below. It still will not check out any files/folders into the folder. It is used to set the folders that will be checked out in the subsequent step.
cd YamlDemo
git sparse-checkout set --no-cone src script



Finally, run the 'git checkout' command to check out the folders specified on the previous 'git sparse-checkout' command.





This is wonderful! In case anyone is interested, you can filter clone with AzDO server as well, but it's disabled by default. Here's a discussion that explains how to enable it.

@TTT, Thanks for your sharing. I was testing on Azure DevOps Services (cloud)  and it can work fine. Yes, on the Azure DevOps Server (on-premises), this feature for Git might be disabled by default and need to be enabled at first.

that is awesome!, thanks heaps @BrightRan-MSFT
whoever created our project put spaces in the names, so accessing the URL i had to use %20
and that meant the folder created looks garbage.. but the process worked.
